# phpIPAM subnet setting inheritance issue

Tags: centos7, ipam

I'm having a problem with phpIpam, and just not really getting anywhere with it, so, hopefully someone might have some clues or insight.

I just did a deployment of phpIPAM, version 1.3.2 (edit, just pulled down to 1.4 from master branch to see if it would help) on a CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core) box. I did a manual load of the subnets from a CSV file that was generated off my equipment directly (so that everything would match up, because sanity). I have the various subnets broken out to the structures desired, however, I'm having problems with the auto host discovery features.

If I go to the furthest child subnet (say a /24), and click the links to edit the subnet properties directly, it'll work fine. A scheduled scan will run, it'll find the hosts, and great.

But when I go to the parent subnets (say the root /22), and click the links to edit the subnet properties, and force it to propagate the changes...they're not propagated. It says that it does, but, it clearly doesn't, and the individual change logs on the child subnets don't.

Anyone ever see anything like this?

Additional notes:

Turning on debugging in the script shows that it doesn't see new hosts for subnet scanning.

Running the discover hosts off the subnet page directly will always yield results (at the least the gateway and addtl. hsrp).

DB is hosted locally.